# How can I make the background of my DirectX window invisible?

Tags: c++, window, directx, background-color, alpha

For example, I am drawing images on the `DirectX11` window. I do not want to show the black background of the window, only the image being drawn. A good example would be of pretty much any `MMORPG` launcher window.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the World of Warcraft launcher alphas out the black background of the `DirectX` window, and only shows the launcher part of the window.

How would I do this in `DirectX` c++?

Comment: The image you post is a customize window, it didn't alphas out the black background(how do you know the that the background is black?), it just paint everything(include the windows and controls on it) itself. look at the area around the `PLAY` button, that's the background color(or image as background) I think.